# VSCODE snippet PHP to fill namespace automatically

Tags: php, regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, regexp-replace

I'm trying to create a [VSCODE CODE SNIPPET](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/snippet-guide) for [PHP](https://php.net) that automatically put the namespace (based on folder path).

The idea is make a substitution on the directory of the current document, considering that all my class are located inside the `MVC` folder, and that this is located inside the `src` folder, examples:

- /dev/project/**src**/MVC/Models/Access/Auth, or
- /home/user/dev/project/**src**/MVC/Models/Access/Auth, or
- /any_other_folder/**src**/MVC/Models/Access/Auth

I got the full folder name with VSCODE snippet variabe `$TM_DIRECTORY`.

Aparently hasn't error on REGEX, as you can see on: https://regex101.com/r/P8CpkX/1

My try of the snipped code:

```
"namep": {
        "prefix": [
            "namep"
        ],
        "body": [
            "",
            "// TM_DIRECTORY: $TM_DIRECTORY",

            "namespace ${TM_DIRECTORY/.*src\/(([^\/]*)(\/)?)|(\/)([^\/]*)/$2\\$5/g};"
        ],
        "scope": "php",
        "description": "Try to put namespace automatically"
    }
```

It results in:

```
// TM_DIRECTORY: /home/user/dev/project/src/MVC/Models/Access/Auth
namespace ${TM_DIRECTORY/.*src/(([^/]*)(/)?)|(/)([^/]*)/$5/g};
```

But the expected is (as demonstrated on [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/P8CpkX/1)):

```
// TM_DIRECTORY: /home/user/dev/project/src/MVC/Models/Access/Auth
namespace \MVC\Models\Access\Auth;
```

Could anyone helps to fix it?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
"namep": {
    "prefix": [
        "namep"
    ],
    "body": [
        "namespace \\\\${TM_DIRECTORY/(?:.*[\\/\\\\])?src[\\/\\\\]([^\\/\\\\]*)[\\/\\\\]?|[\\/\\\\]([^\\/\\\\]*)/$1\\$2/g}",
    ],
    "scope": "php",
    "description": "Try to put namespace automatically"
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7gHOkw/2).

It matches

- `(?:.*[\/\\])?` - an optional occurrence of any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then either `\` or `/`
- `src[\/\\]` - an `src` string and then `/`/`\`
- `([^\/\\]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `/` and `\`
- `[\/\\]?`- an optional `/`/`\` char
- `|` - or
- `[\/\\]` - a `\` or `/` char
- `([^\/\\]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `/` and `\`

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Trying to understand: To "/any_other_folder/src/MVC/Models/Access/SubFolderEndssrc/Auth" the regex caputured "MVC" in group 1, and the array ["Access", "SubFolderEndssrc", "Auth"] in group 2. "Model" wasn't captured.... how this substitution works "$1\\$2", why it join group1 + 'Model' (not caputured) + group2.... and replaced '/' with '\' too? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AllanAndrade When Group 1 does not match, ``$1``  is empty, so the ``\`` + Group 2 value is returned. As `Models` part is not matched, it is not replaced, and is kept in the resulting string.

Comment: @AllanAndrade I left out the initial ``\``, I added it just now. So, use ``"namespace \\\\${TM_DIRECTORY/(?:.*[\\/\\\\])?src[\\/\\\\]([^\\/\\\\]*)[\\/\\\\]?|[\\/\\\\]([^\\/\\\\]*)/$1\\$2/g}",``

Comment: Wiktor, Thank you again!  I updated it with you comment above!

Comment: Magento 2 version (for classes under app/code): `"namespace ${TM_DIRECTORY/(?:.*[\\/\\\\])?code[\\/\\\\]([^\\/\\\\]*)[\\/\\\\]?|[\\/\\\\]([^\\/\\\\]*)/$1\\$2/g};"`

Answer (score 1):

Using `$1\$2` as replace string results in strange matches, the `Models` string is never matched.

An alternative is to not match an ending separator in group/alternative 1

```json
  "namep": {
    "prefix": ["namep"],
    "body": ["namespace ${TM_DIRECTORY/.*[\\/\\\\]src[\\/\\\\]([^\\/\\\\]+)|[\\/\\\\]([^\\/\\\\]+)/\\${1}${2}/g}",],
    "scope": "php",
    "description": "Try to put namespace automatically"
  }
```

- `.*[/\\]src[/\\]` : search for `src` as a directory name
- `([^/\\]+)` : Group 1: a directory name after the `src` directory
- `|` : separating alternatives
- `[/\\]` : a directory separator
- `([^/\\]+)` : Group 2: a directory name

You want each directory name in the result prepended with a \ and group 1 or group 2 is empty so we can use the replace string: `\$1$2`