# How can I create a VSCode snippet to automatically insert namespace of files inside my src folder?

Tags: php, regex, visual-studio-code, regex-group, vscode-snippets

First off, I have the following psr-4 declaration for the `src` folder inside my `composer.json` file:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Src\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

I would like to build a VSCode snippet that autogenerates the namespace of a new file that resides inside the `src` folder.

So far I have this inside `php.json`:

```
    "Namespace Src": {
        "prefix": "ns_src",
        "body": [
            "namespace ${RELATIVE_FILEPATH};",
        ],
        "description": "Namespace for file routes inside the src folder"
    },
```

Taking as an example the following file:

```
src/MyEntity/Application/MyUseCase.php
```

The desired result would be:

```
namespace Src\MyEntity\Application;
```

And right now this is what it returns to me:

```
namespace src/MyEntity/Application/MyUseCase.php;
```

So I need to tackle:

- Upper case of src.
- Replacement of forward slashes `/` into back slashes `\`.
- Removal of everything that is after the last forward slash `/`.

I know there has to be a way to do this with regex. I have read this similar problem ([VSCODE snippet PHP to fill namespace automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67227870/vscode-snippet-php-to-fill-namespace-automatically)) but I haven't quite got the hang of it after reading it.
And I think the upper case problem could maybe be solved with `\F` as in here:
[https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html#:~:text=In%20the%20regex%20%5CU%5Cw,is%20not%20a%20word%20character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html#:%7E:text=In%20the%20regex%20%5CU%5Cw,is%20not%20a%20word%20character).

Is this the right approach? Could you give me any tips on this problem?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
"Namespace Src": {
    "prefix": "ns_src",
    "body": [
        "namespace ${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/^(?:.*[\\\\\\/])?(src)(?=[\\\\\\/])|[\\\\\\/][^\\\\\\/]*$|([\\\\\\/])/${1:+Src}${2:+\\\\}/g};",
     ],
    "description": "Namespace for file routes inside the src folder"
},
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FVsryR/1). *Details*:

- `^(?:.*[\\\/])?(src)(?=[\\\/])` - start of string (`^`), then an optional occurrence of any zero or more chars as many as possible (`.*`) and a `\` or `/` char (`[\\\/]`), and then `src` captured into Group 1, that is immediately followed with `/` or `\`
- `|` - or
- `[\\\/][^\\\/]*$` - a `\` or `/` char and then zero or more chars other than `/` and `\` till end of string
- `|` - or
- `([\\\/])` - Group 2: a `\` or `/` char.

The `${1:+Src}${2:+\\\\}` replacement replaces in this way:

- `${1:+Src}` - if Group 1 matched, replace with `Src`
- `${2:+\\\\}` - if Group 2 matched, replace with `\`.

Answer (score 2):

```
"Namespace Src": {
    "prefix": "ns_src",
    "body": [
      "namespace ${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/^(?:.*[\\\\\\/])?(src)(?=[\\\\\\/])|[\\\\\\/][^\\\\\\/]*$|([\\\\\\/])/${1:+Src}${2:+\\\\}/g};",

            // my version
      "namespace ${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/^([^\\\\\\/]+)|[\\\\\\/][^\\\\\\/]*$|([\\\\\\/])/${1:/capitalize}${2:+\\\\}/g};",
    ],
    "description": "Namespace for file routes inside the src folder"
}
```

Riffing off the other answer - this captures the leading directory and capitalizes it whatever it is called.  Unclear whether you want it work for `src` folder only.

Leading directory:  `([^\\\\\\/]+)`